# What does the following gnuradio error message mean?

Tags: gnuradio

What  does the following gnuradio error message mean?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bill/gr-iio/iio-examples/top_block.py", line 15, in <module>
    from gnuradio import iio
ImportError: cannot import name iio

>>> Done (return code 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS then you can install [`gr-iio`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gr-iio) package:

```
sudo apt-get install gr-iio
```

then test it

```
$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gnuradio import iio
>>>
```

---

For previous versions according to this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/gr-iio/issues/11) we need to compile `gr-iio` first.

The guide is presented on [AnalogDevices Wiki](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/gnuradio?&#compiling_the_gr-iio_blocks_for_your_pc). You can try to follow it.

Comment: That got everything rolling. For some reason I must have had a mis spell on the gr-iio package name.